# php session variables on multiple pages not working

Tags: php, session, variables

```php
<?php
//page 1
session_start();
// codes...
$_SESSION['user_name_loggedin'] = $user;
header("Location: profile.php");
// codes...
?>
```

```php
<?php
//page2
session_start();
// codes...
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name_loggedin'])){
    echo $_SESSION['user_name_loggedin'];
}else{
    echo 'not set<br>';
}
// codes...
?>
```

I am trying to get a login working on my site using sessions. Above shows examples of the two pages I wish to transfer information between using a session. $user is taken from the login form on the login page. On the profile page, after logging in, it only shows 'not set'. Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your browser allow cookies?

Comment: is $user serializeable?

Comment: Make sure $user has a value on the login page. If that value is not being retrieved from the form, the SESSION variable will not be set. Try printing out $user, and commenting out the redirect header. See if there is a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried it locally using the following code:

1 test.php

```
`<?php
//page 1
session_start();
$user="dvjnvki";
$_SESSION['user_name_loggedin'] = $user;
header("Location: b.php");
?>`
```

2 b.php

```
<?php
//page2
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name_loggedin'])){
echo $_SESSION['user_name_loggedin'];
}else{
echo 'not set<br>';
}
?>
```

and it does work perfectly. So the issue with your code might be that you might not be getting a value for the variable called $user. Try to echo that first and see if you get an output.